# Cannot add *.amazonaws.com to trusted sites in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer-11

I am having trouble adding `*.amazonaws.com` to the trusted sites in Internet Explorer 11 (I am using the default browser shipped with Windows Server 2019)

[image: amazonaws-com-internet-explorer-11]

I had tried the following combinations too, with the same error result:

- `*.amazonaws.com`
- `*.amazonaws.*`
- `*://*.amazonaws.com`
- `http://*.amazonaws.com`
- `https://*.amazonaws.com`
- etc

Since Internet Explorer is being difficult, I wanted to circumvent this by just adding the registry keys manually via PowerShell, using the following:

```
Set-Location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set-Location "ZoneMap\EscDomains"
New-Item "amazonaws.com"
Set-Location "amazonaws.com"
New-ItemProperty . -Name * -Value 2 -Type DWORD
```

This doesn't seem to produce the correct output...

[image: strange result]

Not sure what I did wrong?

I also submitted the bug to the Microsoft Community [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/cannot-add-amazonawscom-to-trusted-sites-in/377c17b7-94c6-4171-92bb-fe7283a98d7f).

Comment: On Windows 10, I get the same error with `https://*.amazonaws.com` but it will let me add `https://*.amazonwas.com` and `https://*.amazonwsa.com` and `https://*.amazonaws.co.uk`, suggesting there's a special case forbidding amazonaws.com

Comment: Did you try to add sites using group policy? If not you can try to set Site to Zone Assignment List policy. like this https://i.postimg.cc/y6DdJ21L/106.png Ref: https://blogs.manageengine.com/active-directory/2018/08/02/securing-zone-levels-internet-explorer.html

Comment: I did a bit of Googling and found that there was some kind of ancient malware called "Amazonaws Redirect Virus" --- I wonder if this is related or not? Maybe this specific domain block was grandfathered into IE11?

Comment: Did you try to set it via group policy as I suggested you in my last comment? If yes, did that approach worked? Can you please share your testing result may help to narrow down the issue.